# Unable to resolve chef host while bringing vagrant machine up with libvirt provider

Tags: networking, vagrant, nat, libvirt, virsh

I have a simple Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.omnibus.chef_version = '12.9.38'
    config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 60
    config.vm.define "node0" do |node0|
        node0.vm.box = "baremettle/ubuntu-14.04"
        node0.vm.hostname = "node0"
        node0.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
        node0.vm.provider :libvirt do |qemu|
            qemu.driver = "kvm"
            qemu.memory = 1024
        end
    end
end
```

And when I try to bring machine up I get the following:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sh install.sh -v 12.9.38 2>&1

Stdout from the command:

ubuntu 14.04 x86_64
Getting information for chef stable 12.9.38 for ubuntu...
downloading https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=12.9.38&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64
  to file /tmp/install.sh.1550/metadata.txt
trying wget...
trying perl...
trying python...
Unable to retrieve a valid package!
Version: 12.9.38

Please file a Bug Report at https://github.com/chef/omnitruck/issues/new
Alternatively, feel free to open a Support Ticket at https://www.chef.io/support/tickets
More Chef support resources can be found at https://www.chef.io/support

Please include as many details about the problem as possible i.e., how to reproduce
the problem (if possible), type of the Operating System and its version, etc.,
and any other relevant details that might help us with troubleshooting.

Metadata URL: https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=12.9.38&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64

DEBUG OUTPUT FOLLOWS:

STDERR from wget:

--2016-06-13 15:54:03--  https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=12.9.38&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64
Resolving omnitruck-direct.chef.io (omnitruck-direct.chef.io)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘omnitruck-direct.chef.io’

STDERR from perl:

Can't locate LWP/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::Simple module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

STDERR from python:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>



Stderr from the command:
```

And after that machine is runnign but chef is not installed. And is I ssh into it and try to ping, for example, google.com, I will get:

```
vagrant@node0:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

But on host machine ping works as expected, without problems.

I'm using default libvirt network:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>bd07c4da-891b-4e37-b1d0-16fabb6581c2</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:79:b9:3b'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Vagrant version is 1.8.1

Virsh version is 1.2.2

Vagrant plugins installed:

- vagrant-libvirt (0.0.33)
- vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)

**UPDATE**:

Adding to hosts(or guests) /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

seems to solve the issue.

But I've never had that problem with virtualbox. Could it be that I missed something in libvirt or vagrant configuration?

Comment: Fix your network/DNS setup. The VM cannot resolve any host names. This is completely independent of Chef.

Comment: Could you, please, provide more information about that? I mean I can ping google.com from host machine without prolems. Or is there another way to check DNS problems?

Comment: But not from inside the VM! That's what counts. I'm not a libvirt pro. Not sure how to add the DNS server for the VM with libvirt DHCP, sorry.

Comment: I'm removing the Chef tag as this is not Chef related other than it being an example of networking being unavailable.